# Python. Can't decode bytes from base64 to JSON

Tags: json, python-3.x, base64, decode, base64url

I have a packages encoded by URL-encoded unpadded base64.
It's looks like this:

```
b'DbMG_38MBgb8ru_RlDE1'
```

So I have a simple code which must turn this JSON bytes to Python object

```
import base64, json
b = b'DbMG_38BBgaI0Kv6kzGK'
a = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(b)
c = json.loads(a)
```

From b'DbMG_38BBgaI0Kv6kzGK'  it should turn out this:

```
[
    {
        "length": 13,
        "payload": {
            "src": 819,
            "dst": 16383,
            "serial": 1,
            "dev_type": 6,
            "cmd": 6,
            "cmd_body": {
                "timestamp": 1688984021000
            }
        },
        "crc8": 138
    }
]
```

But I have an error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position 1: invalid start byte
```

Also I have tried:

```
c = a.decode('utf-8') # UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position 1: invalid start byte
c = a.decode('utf-16') # UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode byte 0x8a in position 14: truncated data
c = a.decode('ascii') # UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

But this is not working

The variable a contains:

```
b'\r\xb3\x06\xff\x7f\x01\x06\x06\x88\xd0\xab\xfa\x931\x8a'
```

Please help me decode this bytes I'm at a dead end

Comment: those bytes are clearly not valid JSON, and clearly couldn't encode the result you expect

Comment: yeah, that's way too short

Comment: Base64 encoded strings are about 33% longer than the encoded content. A valid Base64 of your example JSON is: `WwogICAgewogICAgICAgICJsZW5ndGgiOiAxMywKICAgICAgICAicGF5bG9hZCI6IHsKICAgICAgICAgICAgInNyYyI6IDgxOSwKICAgICAgICAgICAgImRzdCI6IDE2MzgzLAogICAgICAgICAgICAic2VyaWFsIjogMSwKICAgICAgICAgICAgImRldl90eXBlIjogNiwKICAgICAgICAgICAgImNtZCI6IDYsCiAgICAgICAgICAgICJjbWRfYm9keSI6IHsKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICJ0aW1lc3RhbXAiOiAxNjg4OTg0MDIxMDAwCiAgICAgICAgICAgIH0KICAgICAgICB9LAogICAgICAgICJjcmM4IjogMTM4CiAgICB9Cl0=`. As you see, it's much longer and totally different from the Base64 you've shown.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga
Calling base64.b64decode(b) results in an error: binascii.Error: Incorrect padding
How then to get JSON from 'DbMG_38BBgaI0Kv6kzGK' or is it impossible?

Comment: Your Base64 contains (whatever kind of) binary data.

Comment: @Nikita that JSON is not being encoded by those b64encoded bytes. The json would require at least 148 bytes to encode as JSON. I don't know enough about compression to be able to say if possibly those bytes are compressed and could contain that JSON... but it would be something like a 7 compression ratio so I think it's unlikely to be any generic compression algorithm

Comment: @jps
Okey, but server send me this short base64 and exists some shell programme which can turn this base64 to JSON, but how she does it I don't know

Comment: @Nikita why do you think that is the case?

Comment: Then you should either use this shell program or analyze what it is doing. But based on the given information your question is not answerable.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga
Okey, if it is not JSON, so how I can decode b'\r\xb3\x06\xff\x7f\x01\x06\x06\x88\xd0\xab\xfa\x931\x8a' if I don't know what encoding is using ?

Comment: @Nikita **why do you think this is even possible*?? How are we supposed to *guess* this? I suspect you are *mistaken* about what these bytes are supposed to represent.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga These bytes really encode json, but it was all about the encoding that was used before using base64, I figured out how to use the encoding I needed, manually wrote the encoder and decoder, and I succeeded. Thank you for your time